# React Native & Redux props correct design pattern

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a react native project and I am using redux actions and reducers to handle my store. 
I have a smart connected component and I call my actions through dispatch in `componentWillMount()` and then I have `mapStateToProps` and I map the data I get from my store to props. 
Problem is the only way to check if the props are changed, is by putting it inside `render` function. In my case I want to navigate to another page if I get props filled with some data. It all works fine but I get warning from React that its anti pattern. Is there any other way of doing this? Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the method [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) instead of comparing the values in the `render`

Another (preferable) approach would be the action responsible to update the values, do the navigation (or dispatch another actions that would do the navigation stuff). Check [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

Comment: Ok thanks. I am already using thunk. Yea I was thinking to do the navigation in Redux as well. Probably thats a better approach

Comment: If you're using [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router), I'd suggest you to use [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) to keep the store synchronized with the navigation. Then it's easy to just dispatch(push('newRoute')) or dispatch(goBack()) within any thunk